# How can I replace script contents of html in a StringBuilder

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, stringbuilder

I have a HTML page in my .Net project in that I have one script section

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    s.property1="|*|property1|*|"
    s.property2="|*|property2|*|"
<script>
```

In the c# code I'm reading the html file and replacing the  "| * |property1| *|" values like below

```
StringBuilder siteCode = new StringBuilder();
//code to append html file to StringBuilder(siteCode)

if(xyz!=null)
{
    siteCode.Replace("|*|property1|*|", xyz);
}
else
{
    //remove s.property1="|*|property1|*|"
}
```

How can I remove s.property1="|*|property1|*|" from `StringBuilder(siteCode)`?

Comment: why not just siteCode.Replace("|*|property1|*|", String.Empty); ?

Comment: i want s.property1(variable) also remove from the string builder.is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [StringBuilder Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method?

`siteCode.Replace("s.property1=\"||property1||\"", "");`